# Programmatically connect with VPN

Tags: android, vpn

I need to connect the VPN using Android code..

I use this library https://github.com/guardianproject/OrbotVPN

But it start the session and send the packets but Server entry is not appear in Interfaces.

In Logcat it Display:

Starting SOCKS Proxy on: 127.0.0.1:9999
tunnel open:true connected:true

I need to connect the server 192.xx.xx.xx

Comment: add more info about your project,like add code or log file here or more details

Comment: But it start the session and send the packets but Server entry is not appear in Interfaces.

In Logcat it Display:

Starting SOCKS Proxy on: 127.0.0.1:9999 tunnel open:true connected:true

I need to connect the server 192.xx.xx.xx